# data is not being displayed vertically in a matlab listbox

Tags: matlab

I am debugging an existing MATLAB program and I figured out how to output large numbers correctly using num2str. My problem is I scan a product and the number is suppose to populate a list box which it does but in stead of a list the numbers are being display horizontally. Like this 1234566 3456789 instead of vertically
Here is how the listbox is set

```
set(Listbox,'string',num2str(evalin('base','SerialScan')));
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what about using a transpose?

Comment: The funny thing is that it works without num2str but an7 number above 6 digits becomes scientific notation.

Comment: Ok and what does SerialScan look like? I guess you could use sprintf to format the digits.

Comment: I am sorry but could you give me an example, I am a noob at matlab :) SerialScan is a variable to hold the serial numbers scanned in. SerialScan = []

Comment: Ok. Then if SerialScan is an array that's quite simple; I'll write an answer to better explain :)

Comment: thanks you it is an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do using sprintf. Look up the doc for sprintf for more formatting options which could be useful as well. For this example, add this line in order to format `SerialScan` and display it vertically as integers:

```
SerialScanFormatted = sprintf('%d|',SerialScan)
```

and then

```
set(Listbox,'string',SerialScanFormatted);
```

Here `%d` tells Matlab to format each number into an integer. The | character is used to displays each number on its own line.

Here is a sample output in a simple GUI:

[image]

Hope that helps get you started!

Comment: @Evanark so did you get to try this answer?

Comment: That works!! Thanks a million. You tought me something new about matlab. Thanks! :)